# Is it possible to add .html at the end of the URL as you like while using NuxtJS or NextJS?

Tags: vue.js, next.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently planning to develop a web application using **NuxtJS/NextJS** framework with SSR Universal architecture, I am facing difficulties related to SEO, because previously my project was written in .NET , so all URLs have `.html` at the end..

Ex:

- domain.com/hotels (this is *Cate*)
- domain.com/hotels-5-star.html (this is a *Sub cate* of Hotels Cate)

The example above is specific to my problem, which means that according to Google, the shorter the URL, the better, so my pages have all been shortened to a single "/", however because of the structure page has 2 hierarchies, Cate and Sub cate, so for Google to distinguish this, the URL (sub cate) must insert `.html` at the end.

Can I use **NuxtJS/NextJS** build pages with the same URL as above?, I have researched but found a specific solution, maybe my experience is not much so I need the help of experts on **NuxtJS/NextJS**

Comment: Why not just use subfolders? Eg., `domain.com/hotels/five-star`? That's how Nuxt's setup to work already.

Comment: @selfagency Good question. According to google, the shorter the URL, the more optimized it will be for SEO, and Google Search will also rate that website higher than other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, in `nuxtjs`, you can use `@nuxtjs/router` to custom your router path like this

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/router'
]
```

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const page = path => () => import(`./pages/${path}.vue`).then(m => m.default || m);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/hotels-:star-star.html',
        name: 'hotels',
        props: true,
        component: page('hotels')
    }
];
export function createRouter(){
    return new VueRouter({
        routes
    });
}
```

**pages/hotels.vue**

```html
<template>
    <main>
        {{ star }}
    </main>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: {
        star: {
            type: Number
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in SEO, but I would just use `5-star` as a query in  `domain.com/hotels`

This would mean you could use the single hierarchy like so:

`domain.com/hotels?rating=5-stars`

As far as using html files as URL routing for the site, the nuxt [`generate`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#exclude) property builds the project into html files which is under your control. The structure comes from what you set in the [pages directory](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/pages/)

Comment: This is fine, but there will be a small problem, assuming you are SEO with the keyword "5 star hotel in New York", then the URL should be `/5-star-hotel-in-new-york.html` is best with Google.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, all modern apps are having some pretty URLs looking like `domain.com/hotels/`
With a trailing slash at the end. Don't mix and match them. Either put them everywhere or nowhere.
SEO-wise, trailing slashes do not matter, you can let them.

Modern JS frameworks are doing a great job at this, and they know that if you reach `domain.com/hotels/`, you're actually wanting to serve the `.html` (aka the `.vue`) file in it, no need to add it.

In Nuxt.js, the directory structures would look like this:

```
-- pages
---- hotels.vue
```

or

```
-- pages
---- hotels
------ index.vue
```

As for this

> the shorter the URL, the better

Don't stress it too much, you don't need to make super shorts paths neither.

Just keep it **semantic** and logic. Having `domain.com/h5s` will be super bad.
Also, having `domain.com/hotels/5-stars` or `domain.com/hotels/?rating=5` is totally fine.
Basically, make them somehow readable for the end user.

---

PS: be aware that Next.js >> React and Nuxt.js >> VueJS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right. But since the old version of my project existed such URL structure, especially for `sub-cate-name.html`, so the migration to **NuxtJS/NextJS** must keep the current URLs as it is,